# Using openoffice draw with Java to convert emf/wmf to png

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I have tried using "freehep" for converting wmf to png. Since the result is really disappointing, I decide to try another solution. My program running under linux OS so imagemagick for converting is not working for me since the wmf/emf features is only supported under windows (not able to use wine as well). However, by using openoffice draw client, i can convert the wmf/emf to png perfectly. But how can I run the function from java? Is there a java api for openoffice draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From libreoffice's man:

```
OPTIONS
       --accept=accept-string
              Specify a UNO connect-string to create a UNO acceptor through which other programs can connect to access the API.
```

So open/libreoffice uses this approach to allow other programs and even client machines to run the program.
My suggestion: forget the complexity and run the following command from your program:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to png /path/to/file.wmfORemf
```

[Here is a link to post describing how to run a command from Java](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016)